# When would one use the replace method of a string?

Tags: ruby

I was messing around and decided to see if `"abcde".replace("a", "e")` would return `"ebcde"`. Turns out this isn't how replace works (I admit I guessed at the method name seeing if one such existed for these purposes).

Instead after reading the docs I found that it has odd behavior.

```
string = "abcde"
string.replace("e") #=> "e"
```

`string` is now `"e"`.

What is the point of the replace method? To me it looks like a setter method, but you could just as easily do `string = "e"`.

Are there specific use-cases for replace?

Comment: Found this link http://www.justskins.com/forums/purpose-of-replace-method-17335.html - if that helps you somewhat in getting the git of the method.

Comment: Yes, that use-case seems to make sense.

Comment: The first method you were looking for is called .tr (translate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-replace) changes the contents of the *current* instance, rather than assigning a new instance. See differences:

```
a = 'old_string'
b = a
b.replace 'new_string'
a
# => "new_string"
```

vs

```
a = 'old_string'
b = a
b = 'new_string'
a
# => "old_string"
```

Comment: indeed, but what is it good for? Most languages can do just fine with immutable strings.

Comment: @JanDvorak you are right, ruby is actually starting to move away from mutable strings...

Comment: For Ruby, if one requires an immutable string, the `freeze` method is great.

Comment: @David yes, but it is a final sign-off then. Never you have access to change it, if really needed.

Comment: True. You'd have to `dup` or `clone` and work with that instead. Would be funny if there was a `heat` method to take off the frozen state.

Comment: @JanDvorak Also true. Never said it'd be smart for there to be a `heat` method :).

Comment: @David I will ask *Matz*  to think about the `#heat` method.. ROFL

Comment: Frozen string literals were actually considered for 2.1 (one suggested form was `"foo"f`) but then were rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Uri's answer:

```
a = "foo"
# => "foo"

a.object_id
# => 70267150553520

a.replace("bar")
# => "bar"

a.object_id
# => 70267150553520
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to change parameter value passed to a method:

```
def change(string)
  string.replace('bar')
end

s = 'foo'
change(s)

s   #=> 'bar'
```